# Proof of inequality $|e^z|\leq e^{|z|}, z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I am trying to prove the inequality $|e^z|\leq e^{|z|}, $ for $ z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$.

My attempt at the proof is the following:

$|e^z|=|e^{x+iy}|=|e^{x}||e^{iy}|=e^x\leq e^{|x|}\leq e^{|z|}$.

Is this correct? I am asking because I have not seen this inequality in any book but it might be useful for certain problems.

In case my proof is not correct, I would like to know what I missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: One possible reason it is hard to find is that you have proved the stronger result $|e^z| = e^{\Re z}$ (which is important, e.g. look in books about the Laplace transform)

Comment: It is correct, compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1649314.

Comment: Another proof would be to develop $e^{z}$ into its Taylor series and use triangle inequality.